# Estou fazendo Throw corretamente?

Tags: java, firebase, exceção, assincronismo

Estou fazendo tipo um DAO do Firebase que realiza e trata o Auth, Database e Storage. Mas os Firebase emite alguns exceptions dependendo do cenário, senha com menos de 6 digitos, email ja cadastrado, etc.

Estou tentando lançar essas exceções para frente usando o throw mas ele pede para eu fazer um try, nao entendi porque se eu estou passando o erro para ser tratado mais para frente porque ele me obriga a tratar o erro.

```
//-------------------- FirebaseAuth ------------------------------
    public void createAuth(User user) {       

       mFirebaseAuth = ConfigurationFirebase.getFirebaseAuth();
       mFirebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(user.getEmail(), user.getPassword()).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
           @Override
           public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                //Fazer algo caso a criação do usuário tenha ocorrido com sucesso.
           }
       }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
           @Override
           public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                  if (e.getClass().equals(FirebaseAuthWeakPasswordException.class)) {

                      try {
                          throw new FirebaseAuthWeakPasswordException(e.getCause().toString(), e.getLocalizedMessage().toString(), e.getMessage().toString());
                      } catch (FirebaseAuthWeakPasswordException e1) {
                          e1.printStackTrace();
                      }

                  } else if (e.getClass().equals(FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException.class)) {

                      try {
                          throw new FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException(e.getCause().toString(), e.getLocalizedMessage().toString());
                      } catch (FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException e1) {
                          e1.printStackTrace();
                      }

                  }
           }
       });

    }
```

Comment: Coloque o código que está causando o problema, a mensagem de erro, e use as tags pra indicar qual linguagem de programação/plataforma você está usando.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso não vai funcionar porque o método que você está chamando é assíncrono. Essa exceção seria lançada para uma outra *thread*, na qual a chamada em rede está ocorrendo, e não ia funcionar de qualquer forma. Esse padrão DAO que você está tentando fazer simplesmente não funciona em paradigmas assíncronos sem alterações.

Você não especificou a linguagem de programação ou ambiente de execução, mas se for um ambiente no qual não há problema em travar a *thread* atual enquanto espera o resultado, você pode usar `Tasks.await` pra fazer seu código esperar até a finalização da `Task` resultante do `createUserWithEmailAndPassword`. Exemplo:

```
public void createAuth(User user) throws FirebaseAuthWeakPasswordException {

    Task<AuthResult> createUserAccountTask = mFirebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(user.getEmail(), user.getPassword());
    try {
        // Nessa linha, a execução da thread atual vai congelar até a tarefa concluir (com sucesso ou erro)
        Tasks.await(createUserAccountTask);

        if (createUserAccountTask.isSuccessful()) {
            //Fazer algo caso a criação do usuário tenha ocorrido com sucesso.
        } else {
            Exception e = createUserAccountTask.getException();
            if (e.getClass().equals(FirebaseAuthWeakPasswordException.class)) {
                throw new FirebaseAuthWeakPasswordException(e.getCause().toString(), e.getLocalizedMessage().toString(), e.getMessage().toString());
            } else if (e.getClass().equals(FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException.class)) {
                throw new FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException(this.e.getCause().toString(), this.e.getLocalizedMessage().toString());
            }
        }

    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        // faça alguma coisa aqui em caso de ExecutionException
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // faça alguma coisa aqui caso a tarefa seja interrompida no meio
    }

}
```

Porém, fique atento que isso pode congelar a tela do usuário caso rode na *thread* principal.

Uma abordagem comum e simples de implementar quando não é possível bloquear a execução da thread atual é usar os chamados *callbacks* ou *listeners*. Você deve exigir que quem chama a sua função passe pra ela, além do usuário e da senha, objetos que explicam o que fazer quando a tarefa for concluída. Por exemplo, você pode definir essas interfaces:

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface UserCreationSuccessfulListener {
    void onUserCreated();
}

@FunctionalInterface
interface UserCreationFailedListener {
    void onFailedToCreateUser(Exception e);
}
```

E então pode mudar a sua função para ser assim:

```
public void createAuth(User user, final UserCreationSuccessfulListener successListener, final UserCreationFailedListener failureListener) throws FirebaseAuthWeakPasswordException {

    mFirebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(user.getEmail(), user.getPassword())
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(AuthResult authResult) {
                    successListener.onUserCreated();
                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

                    if (e.getClass().equals(FirebaseAuthWeakPasswordException.class)) {
                        failureListener.onFailedToCreateUser(
                                new FirebaseAuthWeakPasswordException(e.getCause().toString(), e.getLocalizedMessage(), e.getMessage())
                        );
                    } else if (e.getClass().equals(FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException.class)) {
                        failureListener.onFailedToCreateUser(new FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException(e.getCause().toString(), e.getLocalizedMessage()));
                    } else {
                        failureListener.onFailedToCreateUser(e);
                    }

                }
            }
            );

}
```

E usá-la assim:

```
createAuth(user, new UserCreationSuccessfulListener() {
    @Override
    public void onUserCreated() {
        // fazer algo aqui em caso de sucesso
    }
}, new UserCreationFailedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFailedToCreateUser(Exception e) {
        // fazer algo aqui em caso de erro
    }
});
```

Ou melhor ainda:

```
createAuth(user, () -> {
    // fazer algo aqui em caso de sucesso
}, (error) -> {
    // fazer algo aqui em caso de erro
});
```

Existem outras opções. Você pode, por exemplo, retornar a própria *Task* que o `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` e deixar o código cliente da sua função se virar com o resultado. Um problema é que isso cria uma dependência do código cliente com a API do Google Play Services.

Comment: Vlw Pablo, para resolver o problema eu poderia rodar os metodos em Threads, um asynctask ou ate mesmo usar um RxAndroid?

Comment: ou ainda o jobdispatcher do firebase?

Comment: Se você está falando da solução 1 que eu dei, se você for usar threads ou asynctasks pra poder fazer ele funcionar, você só está repassando a complexidade de um ponto pro outro. E o pior: pode acabar tendo que replicar lógica de tratamento de threads e asynctasks em vários lugares, caso o método seja chamado várias vezes. Não é interessante. O melhor é aceitar a natureza assíncrona da função e criar APIs assíncronas mesmo. O RxAndroid é uma opção, sim, mas eu pessoalmente o acho mais adequado para situações mais complexas, como um callback que é chamado várias vezes, por exemplo.

Comment: A própria API [Tasks](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/tasks) do Google Play Services é muito legal, e o Firebase já usa ela nativamente, então você não vai precisar ficar fazendo conversões. Se você não tiver problemas em aprender a usá-la, é uma boa.

Comment: Eu entendi o motivo de usar um RX ou um AsyncTask, a preocupação seria alem de tirar o processamento da Activity por conta de infringir a regra de nao fazer processamentos paralelos pesados na UIthread, ter que atualizar alguma view que so pode ser feito pela UiThread.

Mas no meu caso eu so quero realizar a tarefa de salvar dados no firebase, buscar dados no firebase etc.

Essa DAO vai retornar Exceptions, booleans etc e na activity vou me virar para usar um handler.post ou algo parecido.

Entao eu posso simplesmente nesse meu DAO usar um new Thread(runnable ) da vida????

Comment: Pablo, para resolver o problema da comunicação assincrona do Android, vc acha melhor:
RXAndroid, Tasks do Google, JobDispatcher do Firebase ou tratar com Interfaces?

Tratar com interfaces esta muito confuso, estou tentando mas não saio do lugar!!!